# Visual Studio Code Tab Key does not insert a tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code as my code editor.
I did a search on google but wasn't able to find anything about my issue.

The issue is simple, pressing <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> in the editor does nothing. I'm expecting it to insert 4 spaces.

Anyone know what I can do to get <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> working like expected?

Comment: I had a problem where tab would just tab outside of the editor (navigating between UI elements). Restarting the editor fixed it.

Comment: Not answering op questions, but for anyone else landing here after searching "visual studio tab not working" or having issue when hitting Tab in Visual Studio selects block instead of adding indentation. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515014/2188407) by [Karel Tamayo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324535/karel-tamayo)

Comment: Remains an issue in Code v1.45.1 from June 2020. Solution is to delete the `Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus` keybinding of `Ctrl + M` (see the answer by @Addison). Strange 'feature'.

Comment: See [VS reference for Tab trapping](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_tab-trapping)

Comment: Thanks!  Pressing `ctrl+M` fixed it for me.  no need to restart

Comment: @AlainD The idea is probably to allow moving around in the editor without leaving the keyboard :)

Comment: MacOS `Ctrl+Shift+M` to return normal tab behavior

Comment: Finally, someone is asking the *real* questions

Comment: @Nearoo Exactly.  Some people are unable to use a mouse so it's an important accessibility feature.

Answer (score 2623):

I had accidentally enabled a different mode for the tab key. Fixed it by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (for Mac), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (for Windows).

From the [Visual Studio Code Keybinding docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings):

> ```
> | Key      | Command                                 | Command id                       |
> | Ctrl + M | Toggle Use of Tab Key for Setting Focus | editor.action.toggleTabFocusMode |
> ```

The current tab control mode should also show up in the status bar:

[image]

Comment: Happened to me when I tried to use the code collapse (`Ctrl + M, Ctrl + O`). Thx.

Comment: What is `Setting Focus ` ?

Comment: Theres a bright green "Tab Moves Focus" on the statusbar at the bottom if you have mistakenly pressed Ctrl+M.

Comment: @Jannunen you're right, sadly for us who have 25inch screens, nobody is gonna notice that teeny tiny thing in the corner...

Comment: What a truly peculiar setting. It's especially confusing because Ctrl-M is used to open up a development menu in the Android emulator (writing in React Native / Expo). I must have accidentally pressed it when VSCode was open and not the emulator.

What a bewilderingly strange feature, though.

Comment: Note: you have to be outside the editor for `Ctrl + m` to switch.

Comment: Delete the keybinding for `Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus` immediately so this never happens again! See answer by @Addison.

Comment: ctrl+M didn't do anything but you can click the Tab Moves Icon in the statusbar in the screenshot above...

Comment: Ctrl + m for Linux as well.

Comment: I changed my shortcut to 'Ctlr + m Ctrl + o' so it will not happen again by accident

Comment: Just stumbled upon this answer and came to upvote it again, only to realize I had already upvoted it in the past haha.

Comment: @Teekin It's not bewilderingly strange, it's to allow moving the focus (as tab does in most contexts) without touching the mouse.  This might be preference for some, and is vital for others, as some people are unable to use a mouse.  The feature is labelled an "Accessibility mode".

Comment: @devrobf I stand corrected. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: This is a wildly stupid "feature". THANK YOU!

Comment: This already happens twice with me, and both i found the solution here.

Answer (score 404):

Click "Tab Moves Focus" at the bottom right in the status bar. That's it.

[image]

I believe I had pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. When doing this, the "Tab Moves Focus" tab/button showed up at the bottom right. Clicking on that makes it go away and starts working again.

You can type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> again to toggle it off as other answers have pointed out, but that's not as easy to remember as just clicking on it.

Comment: Saved me, I do not know how I enabled it but I installed a new keyboard and suddenly TAB was jumping into different windows.

Comment: Microsoft products have many rubbish built in. another famous is Multiple Desktop in Windows 10, or unable to Create Desktop Shortcut in Windows 10 . so when you try to add Shortcut for Skype App into Desktop, good luck

Comment: ctrl + M toggling solve the issue

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. I have no idea how this happened, but it was exactly my problem also. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 340):

#### To fix the issue

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>  causes the <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>  key to move focus instead of inserting a <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>  character.
Turn it off by pressing the shortcut again.

#### To disable the shortcut

1. Open "Keyboard Shortcuts" with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
   Or go to *File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*.
2. Search for `toggle tab key moves focus`.
3. Right Click, `Remove Keybinding`.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I use `ctrl + m` -> `ctrl + k` -> `ctrl + 0` to collapse code and almost daily I accidentally break my tab functionally before this :)

Comment: I just installed MSVS 2019. I don't see Preferences under the File tab. ctrl-k, ctrl-s opens a list of snippets. I don't see a "toggle tab key moves focus" option. Which version of MSVS are you using?

Comment: @riderBill - This is for the latest VS Code 1.39.2 (2019-10-15). You are using [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio), which is not to be confused with [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code).

Comment: Oh. <:^| My mistake. But not (entirely) my fault. I'll plead "Microsoft is an industry leader in poor choices for naming new products." As is Google. Ever try to search for help on Google Messages? [Sigh]

Comment: With no obvious indication as to what's happening, what an utterly stupid UI design. Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+M` for MacOS to restore normal tab behavior

Answer (score 97):

Click on the explorer or any other window that is not the editor then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> (for Mac only) + <kbd>M</kbd>, this is the command to "Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus" on the Keyboard Shortcuts.

Comment: Is there any way to disable this "feature" ?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett just remove the keybinding

Answer (score 26):

In, my case I followed [this advice](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20209#issuecomment-278428711) and changed this emmet setting in vscode to `false`:

```json
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": false
```

I was receinving the error `Cannot read property 'value' of null`. It solved the problem immediatelly.

Comment: This worked only after doing ctrl+m as well (perhaps because I had tried some of the other suggestions without success before trying this).

Answer (score 22):

Try  CTR + M it will work like before.

Answer (score 16):

As of December 2018 on macOS Mojave 10.14.2 using VSCode 1.29.1 the default keybinding for 'Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus' is set to `Command+Shift+M`.  If you got stuck with this, using that key combo should fix the issue.

Do `Command+K Command+S` to pull up the Hotkeys Settings and then search for `Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus` or `editor.action.toggleTabFocusMode` if you want to change the key combo.

Comment: On Windows it's just `Ctrl+M` by default to `Toggle Tab Key Moves Focus`. And Dan, that's a tad hyperbolic, considering the default in Visual Studio to format a document is actually Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D - http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/

Answer (score 11):

Had this problem. Simply press "Ctrl + M" (On Windows). Likely "CMD+M" on Mac.

Answer (score 9):

I am using code on **xfce** - did the following to fix the Tab key behavior:

File -> Preferences -> Settings

search for **"keyboard.dispatch"**

copy to right panel and **change value from "code" to "keyCode"**

Reload code

Answer (score 9):

[Edit] This answer is for MSVS (the IDE, as opposed to VS *Code*). It seems Microsoft and Google go out of their way to choose confusing names for new products. I'll leave this answer here for now, while I (continue to) look for the equivalent stackoverflow question about *MSVS*. Let me know in the comments if you think I should delete it. Or better, point me to the *MSVS* version of this question.

I installed MSVS 2017 recently. None of the suggestions I've seen fixed the problem. The solution I figured out works for MSVS 2015 and 2017. Add a comment below if you find that it works for other versions.

Under Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> General, try unchecking the "Automatically indent when I type a tab" box. It seems counter intuitive, but it fixed the problem for me. 
[image]

Comment: Same in VS Community 2022. This is a mislabeled option. Yes, I want tab to indent, but I still want tab to work to format other parts of the line if not at the beginning. The VS2022 IDE disables `tab` if not used at the beginning of the line if this option is checked. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

All the above failed for me.
But I noticed <kbd>shift</kbd>  + <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>  worked as expected (outdenting the line).

So I looked for the "Indent Line" shortcut (which was assigned to <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>cmd</kbd>  + <kbd>0</kbd> ), assigned it to tab, and now I'm happy again.

---

**Next morning edit...**

I also use tab to accept snippet suggestions, so I've set the "when" of "Indent Line" to `editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !inSnippetMode && !suggestWidgetVisible`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for figuring out a functioning `when` condition.

Answer (score 5):

For those of you not about that **space bar life** (- _ - )( - _ -)

1. Keybinding for <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>  isn't set to anything so you have to do it manually
2. Navigate to Preferences/Environment/Keybindings and search for "**tab**"
3. Click on Edit Binding at the bottom and press the tab key.
4. Press "**Apply**" then "**Ok**"
5. Key bound!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe another program is interfering? Closing Teamviewer fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Same for me!!! I never open a TeamViewer, and I accidentally left it open.
To add more info: I had another instance of VS Code running, and in it the tab was working fine, while in the other tab was not working. After closing TeamViewer, tab works in both instances!

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, after an update, my tab key was unbinded of 'tab' default behaviour. So I have to open **File>Preferences>Keyboad Shortcuts**, search for the simple "tab" line, and bind to the tab key again. Pretty awkward, but worked.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this happen before as well, where there was TeamViewer client takes the control of the TAB key. You won't know this until you close the TV window that you have open in the background.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac,
Preferences -> settings -> Search for "tab"
Uncheck `Insert spaces when pressing tab`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your key mapping (File > Preferences > Key Mapping) [Ctrl+K Ctrl+S].
In the input line at the top write 'tab' and bind **tab command** with **tab key**.

It works for me. Some extension overwrite it.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me.

If your tab is not inserting space but focusing button element then following solution will work for you :)

Just set a keybindings to tab command like following image.

[image: If your tab is not inserting space instead focusing then following solution will work for you]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is NOT checked  :

[  ] Tools | Options | Text Editor | C/C++ | Formatting | Automatic Indentation On Tab

Let me know if this helped!

Comment: Is this related with Visual Studio? The question is asked for VS Code I guess.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, above not working any more, Microsoft changed the key binding

On Mac, Cmd + shift + M no longer working

Instead you should use :   ctrl  + shift + M

Here is evidence:
[image]

Comment: Ctrl+M still works for me on vscode 1.64.1 on Windows. What version of vscode are you on?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Mac.
The `Ctrl + Shift + M` solution was not the correct one in my case. The indentation of a code line when pressing the Tab key was not possible because the key binding for indentation was set to a 4-key combination.

I did reset it to the Tab key in the key bindings settings (Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts) and added `&& !config.emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` to the when expression, since I use the emmet plugin.

Answer (score -1):

### Problem could be caused by an Application on your computer

For me the problem got solved after closing `Any Desk` on my computer . I had it open to change some files on my remote server, and it's blocking the ability to `tab`

If you want to check , open your task manager and you will find it there. just right click it and select `end task` and `tab` will be back to normal.

[image: AnyDesk]

Answer (score -2):

None of the above worked for me. For me, the issue was that the file wasn't editable by VSCode. You'll see a small padlock on the file tab on top. Just close the tab and open the file again. Tab should be working as usual.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure what operating system you're on, but there was a known issue with the tab key on one of the more recent releases of VS Code for Mac OS X. The bug has been fixed in the latest release (0.10.9).

On Mac OS X, you can check for the latest update by opening VS Code and then going to [Code > Check for Updates].

Sources and more information:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates

Comment: The latest update didn't do it for me - I pulled the March insiders release and that worked great.