# How to disable resharper 2016.2 tab key inside a class

Tags: resharper

resharper has this new tab key rule within a class, when tab, it will convert tab into to navigation to the next part of the code but not adding tab spacing between them. does anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hitting Tab in Visual Studio selects block instead of adding indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514915/hitting-tab-in-visual-studio-selects-block-instead-of-adding-indentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called Structural Navigation, and will select code as you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (very useful for tabbing between parameters, for example). You can change the behaviour in options, under Editor Behaviour. You can find [more details on the feature and how it works in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Navigation_and_Search_Structural_Navigation.html).

Comment: Useful indeed but the current ciding style require all properties type,  names and get set bracket to align vertically (don't ask why).  Whats the name of the rule in the editor behavior?

Comment: "Structural Navigation" :)