# How to turn on Path Autofill in Visual Studio Code using the "Tab" key?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Previously, when I started typing "cd type-folder-name-partially-here" and clicked "Tab" on my keyboard, VS Code it would autofill the folder or file path, but now the "Tab" key navigates me around the code editor instead of doing that.

How can I make it so the "Tab" key autofills the folder or file path like it did before?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem wasn't specific to my terminal alone. I discovered while coding that "Tab" also failed to insert 4 spaces into my code.

I found the answer that resolved my tab issue on StackOverflow:

[Tab Key Issue - Answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35519538/visual-studio-code-tab-key-does-not-insert-a-tab)